# Template Routes and extra segments

Tags: templates

I often use a 'site' template group to house my base level pages. For example I may have a 'about' page, but don't require an 'about' template group so I add this to the 'site' group. I then don't want the URL to be /site/about so I have always used the plugin 'freeway' to allow me to remove the 'site' part (domain.com/about).

Now that 'Template Routes' has arrived, I have begun using this by setting '/about' as the route for the page. This works perfectly.

The problem I have is that on occasion I add a segment on a page to show additional information when a user clicks a link. For example 'about/more-content'. Now with template routes this extra segment stops the page from working and shows the 404 page.

Is there a way to have '/about' as the route, but also allow for extra segments after?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like it'd be a lot simpler to just have a few more template groups...;)

Answer (score 4):

Yup - make sure you set "require all segments" to "no", then just add another segment to the rule:

```
/about/{extra:alpha_dash}
```

`:alpha_dash` means that the segment can contain alpha-numeric characters, underscores, and dashes. [There are other rules available as well.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#rules)

Then in your template you can check the value of the extra segment this way:

```
{if segment:extra == 'foo'}
    // Show something different
{/if}
```