# Template Routing with extra segments, how to catch 404's?

Tags: 404, template-routes

I'm using the extra segment approach to direct requests to pages, as described here:

[Template Routes and extra segments](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/template-routes-and-extra-segments)

This is working great and allows me to create a common wrapper for pages, but how do I deal with 404's?

It doesn't seem to matter what I set 'Template to be used as the 404 error page' to it still directs to the index/index template, which contains the following:

```
{embed='pages/{segment:extra}'}
```

and so always gets 'resolved'.

is there a way that I can test that this calls a valid page:
{embed='pages/{segment:extra}'}

Or is there another approach I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your index page not have any restriction to check weather the entry exists or not. You can do this with various ways. Best way is to put a condition under channel entry of that page that will redirect to 404 if no entry is match with it.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="CHANNEL_NAME"
    disable="custom_fields|categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships"

    {!--No parameters if your entries URL title is last segment--}
    {!--OR--}
    {!--If you have entry_id--}
    dynamic="no" entry_id="{ENTRY_ID}"

    {!--If you have URL title--}
    dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_2}"

    {!--If page is dynamic (Pages module redirct page or some way dynamic page) --}
    require_entry="yes"
}

    {!-- Syntax to call 404 is {redirect="404"} --}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}

    {!--My channel content etc.--}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```